# $\text{Mod}(A)$ is an $E_n$ category $\Leftrightarrow$ $A$ is an ??? algebra

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, quantum-groups, infinity-categories

Say we're working in a symmetric monoidal $\infty$-category $\mathcal{S}$, and $A$ is an associative algebra in it. For instance,
$$\mathcal{S}\ =\ \text{dg vector spaces},\ \ \ A\ =\ \text{a dg algebra}.$$
Then:

1. $\text{Mod}(A)=\text{Mod}_\mathcal{S}(A)$ is just a plain category, no extra structure (i.e. an $E_0$ category).
2. $A$ is a *bi*algebra iff $\text{Mod}_\mathcal{S}(A)$ is an $E_1$ category, i.e. is monoidal, and if the forgetful functor is monoidal.
3. $A$ is a *quasitriangular* *bialgebra* (e.g. quantum group) iff $\text{Mod}_\mathcal{S}(A)$ is an $E_2$ category, i.e. is braided monoidal, and if the forgetful map to $\mathcal{S}$ is a braided monoidal functor.
4. (This next step is what my question is about)

**Question:** What about for slightly higher $n$, like $E_3,E_4,E_5,...$? Is there a simple definition of what $A$ has to be in that case? Are there examples of such $A$ coming up in real life? Quantum groups are extremely interesting and deep objects, so one imagines that the next ones along will be even more interesting.

Comment: Are the iff's theorems? If so does the theorem not depend on what you choose as the unit of the monoidal structure? Anyways left modules over E_{n+1} algebras form En categories, in case you didn't know that. Not sure how exactly it relates to the other structures you mentioned but highly likely to be related

Comment: I don't think that's what the question is about. Given the answer for $n=1$, it seems like OP doesn't want $A$ to be the unit of $Mod(A)$, but wants the forgetful functor to be strict ($E_n$-)monoidal

Comment: I suspect the difference between what i said and the examples you have is that the tensor product in what I mentioned has A as the unit and i think for these bialgebras the ground ring is the unit? Sorry I'm mostly guessing here

Comment: @Maxime I agree, but in this case doesn't there exist a lot of choices for A? Like if i pick any compact generator is there always some bialgebra structure on it? Anyway i would say that the two stories are still very connected because often one can form the algebras in the OP as shadows of En algebras I believe. For instance for Lie algebras, one can take k tensor k over some E2 rings and recover the enveloping algebra.

Comment: @davik : the question is not about whether such structures exist, but rather what they are classified by (as far as  I understand). So : how to understand, in terms of $A$, such a structure on $Mod(A)$ ?

Comment: Right, but i just asked that because if it is actually if and only if i should be able to go backwards and get the bialgebra structure. Sorry i agree this is not exactly the spirit of the question, which is very interesting, I'm just confused why the if and only if statements are true and if they are what is the precise formulation

Comment: @davik : Yes, they are - I'm writing an answer and mentioning it along the way :)

Comment: There is an AFAIK folkloric construction that might be relevant here: write an E_{n+1}-algebra as an E_1 algebra in E_n algebras, and apply (contravariant) Koszul duality. this should give an (E_1, co-E_n)-bialgebra structure. So in the case of quasi-triangular Hopf algebras like U_q(g), these should be dual to some E_3 algebras (local observables in Chern-Simons theory). With this heuristic in mind it does seem like most interesting non-tautological examples will be low-dimensional, since that is where we know more about TQFTs. Can find this idea in a lot of recent work of K. Costello.

Comment: also I seem to recall that an E_3 ordinary category is symmetric monoidal. So one needs homotopy or higher categories to see such structures. I believe that the derived Satake category of Bezrukavnikov-Finkelberg is supposed to be an example of an E_3 category "in the wild." This ought to be a little bit intuitive if you've seen the relevant objects (Hecke modifications compose, and they also factorize on the curve), but the details are not at all trivial.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$E_0$ is not quite "no extra structure" : you know who $A$ is inside $Mod(A)$, so it's a *pointed* category (more generally, an $E_0$ object in $\mathcal S$ is an object with a "unit" $\mathbb 1\to X$).

For a different version of your question, the answer is "$A$ is $E_{n+1}$ iff $Mod(A)$ is $E_n$", where "iff" can be made more precise : the space of $E_n$-structures on the $E_0$-category $Mod(A)$ (i.e. the space of $E_n$-structures where $A$ is the unit) is equivalent to the space of $E_{n+1}$-structures on $A$ extending its $E_1$-structure.

But that does not seem to be the question you're asking, you seem to be asking about monoidal structures on $Mod(A)$ such that the forgetful functor $Mod(A)\to \mathcal S$ is *strict* monoidal - at least that's how I understand your answer for $n=1$ (you say "bialgebra", where the previous paragraph hints at $E_2$-algebra, which shows we aren't thinking of the same thing).

So what's the answer for your version of the question ? To answer this, I'll make a few observations. But before that, I'll set the stage, where probably the assumptions are not necessary but they'll make things easier: I'll assume $\mathcal S$ is presentably symmetric monoidal, so that I can work in $\mathcal S$-modules in $Pr^L$ and have a nicely behaved Lurie tensor product $\otimes_\mathcal S$.

1- The functors appearing in your structure are of the form $Mod(A)\otimes_\mathcal S Mod(A)\to Mod(A)$, over $\mathcal S \simeq \mathcal S\otimes_\mathcal S\mathcal S\to \mathcal S$, or variations thereon with more tensor products. One of the nice properties of $\otimes_\mathcal S$ is that $Mod(A)\otimes_\mathcal S Mod(B) \simeq Mod(A\otimes B)$. In particular your functors are of the form $Mod(A\otimes A)\to Mod(A)$, over $\mathcal S$. Because limits are preserved and reflected by the forgetful functors, your functors preserve both limits and colimits.

2- In particular, the full subcategory of $Mod_\mathcal S(Pr^L)_{/\mathcal S}$ on objects of the form $Mod(A)\overset{forgetful}\to \mathcal S$ is closed under tensor products where the monoidal structure on $Mod_\mathcal S(Pr^L)_{/\mathcal S}$ is the usual one on $C_{/A}$ where $A$ is an algebra: the tensor product is given by $(X\to A)\otimes (Y\to A) := (X\otimes Y\to A\otimes A\to A)$. You can make this more precise and actually make this into a monoidal category (as monoidal as $A$ is in $C$). It's closed under tensor products, but also every functor there is both in $Pr^R$ and in $Pr^L$.

3- The structure you're interested in is the structure of an $E_n$-algebra on $Mod(A)\to \mathcal S$, viewed in $Mod_\mathcal S(Pr^L)_{/\mathcal S}$. By the point just above, this is the same as the structure of an $E_n$-coalgebra in $Mod_\mathcal S(Pr^L)_{\mathcal S/}$ on the object $\mathcal S\overset{-\otimes A}\to Mod(A)$

4- Lurie proves in *Higher Algebra* that $Alg(\mathcal S)\to Mod_\mathcal S(Pr^L)_{\mathcal S/}$ is an equivalence of symmetric monoidal $\infty$-categories. So the structure you're after is exactly that of an $E_n$-coalgebra in algebras.

For $n=1$ you recover the notion of bialgebra. For $n=2$, I'm not sure what a quasitriangular bialgebra is, but if your condition is an "iff", then it should be the same data as an algebra $A$ together with a comultiplication $A\to A\otimes A$ (which is an algebra map) which is $E_2$-cocommutative as an algebra map, in a highly coherent sense. What comes later is just more and more cocommutativity for this map.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So a quasitriangular bialgebra is something quite explicit (http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/quasitriangular+bialgebra), do you know what the equivalent definition is for $E_3$? And, do you know any examples of these things being important/appearing unexpectedly, e.g. in geometry? Like the fact that quantum groups $U_q(\mathfrak{g})$ appear everywhere.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know the answer to these more specific questions . The definition for quasitriangular seems a bit odd, though, because if $\mathcal S$ is a $1$-category (such as $k$-vector spaces), $E_2$ should be the same as commutative. So I'm a little bit confused here.

Comment: Let $A$ be an ordinary $k$-algebra ($k$ a field), and suppose you have a braided monoidal structure on $Mod(A)$ with a braided monoidal structure on the forgetful functor. Then the iterated braiding forgets to the identity of $k$-vector spaces, therefore it must be the identity because the forgetful functor is faithful - are you sure you want the forgetful functor to be braided monoidal and not just monoidal ? In the latter case that would make my answer inappropriate

Comment: Beautiful answer, I learned a lot.

Comment: If $\mathcal S$ is a $1$-category, then the forgetful functor from $A$-modules to $\mathcal S$ is always faithful : $\hom_A(M,N)$ is the subset of $\hom(M,N)$ on $A$-linear maps

Comment: Thanks sorry i forgot you are on 1 categories for a second...